# Can't get r code for show %s and colors for grouped bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've look up so many sample code snippets online but for the life of me I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong. I've included the r code below that gives me this chart:

[image: unsatisfying r chart]

It's generally working, except:

1. I can't get it to show %s instead of counts (for the factor variable "doctorate"), and
2. The colors for "group" show up in the legend, but not in the bars themselves.

```
pg_doc <- ztemp.pg %>%
  ggplot(aes(doctorate, group = group)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = ..prop.., fill = group), stat="count") + 
  geom_bar(position = position_dodge(preserve = "single")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("grey45","goldenrod2")) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.title=element_blank(),
        text = element_text(color="black"), #for x & y axis text labels
        axis.text.x = element_text(color="black", size=10, hjust=1),
        axis.text.y = element_text(color="black"),
        axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        plot.title=element_text(hjust=.5))+
  ggtitle("Highest degrees attained by leadership")+
  scale_x_discrete(labels= c("Other", "Doctorate"))

pg_doc
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write one geom_bar. You can also move `fill` argument to the `aes` command in `ggplot`function. To show percentages, you have to calculate them apriori and plot. A simple reproducible example will provide more clarity.

```
pg_doc <- ztemp.pg %>%
      ggplot(aes(doctorate, group = group)) +
      geom_bar(aes(y = ..prop.., fill = group), stat="count",position = position_dodge(preserve = "single")) +
      scale_fill_manual(values=c("grey45","goldenrod2")) +
      theme(legend.position = "bottom",
            legend.title=element_blank(),
            text = element_text(color="black"), #for x & y axis text labels
            axis.text.x = element_text(color="black", size=10, hjust=1),
            axis.text.y = element_text(color="black"),
            axis.title.x=element_blank(),
            axis.title.y=element_blank(),
            plot.title=element_text(hjust=.5))+
      ggtitle("Highest degrees attained by leadership")+
      scale_x_discrete(labels= c("Other", "Doctorate"))

    pg_doc
```